In Rust what is the best way to copy an option<string> or its default value to another string?
this is a sample question and I figure out two methods to do this:
let s = Some("hello".to_string());
let d = "world".to_string();
// method 1
let v = s.clone().unwrap_or(d).clone();
// method 2
let v = s.as_ref().unwrap_or(&d).clone();
println!("{:?} {} {}", s, d, v);

I feel that both methods are a bit redundant. Is there a more concise way to do this?

I'd vote for s.clone().unwrap_or_else(|| d.clone()) as the clearest. It's reasonably short and also idiomatic, communicating the intention to the human reader.

You can always defer the clone, as in: s.as_ref().unwrap_or("world").to_string()

@tadman: that's pretty much the OP's method 2, is it not?  Actually I think you'd need to use .as_deref() in your case because the string literal is &str whereas the s.as_ref() will produce Option<&String>?

Rust compiler give a suggestion: let v = s.clone().unwrap_or(d.clone()); Is this Ok?

@kyleqian: No, that's definitely not a good idea as it will needlessly clone d when s is Some.  You could use .unwrap_or_else(|| d.clone()) to perform that clone lazily, but I think others have already given you better suggestions.

@eggyal It's close, but there's no need to keep the d around as a String, just leave it as a &'static str in some const or as an argument if it only shows up once. I also called to_string() vs. clone() as that should give you a String, for sure. to_owned() also equivalent. The method 2 should give you a "clone" of a &str, which is not really a clone at all.

@tadman But method 2 works fine and v is String. s and d is String variables come from outter code.

Assuming you're asking from an efficiency point of view.
Method 1 is always bad, if s is set it gets cloned twice which is unnecessary. But as eggyal notes you can just remove the final clone() which is not necessary. In that case it's fine iff d is always computed anyway (e.g. as the side effect of some previous process).
Method 2 is fine if d is always a reference, otherwise it leads to an unnecessary copy of that.
In the likely case where d only needs to be computed if s is unset, then
s.as_ref().map_or_else(
    // lazily compute d
    || "world".to_string(),
    String::clone,
)

could be a good choice.
You may find a less functional version more readable as well e.g.
if let Some(s) = &s {
    s.clone()
} else {
    "world".to_string()
}

YMMV

Isn't the second clone at the end of method 1 entirely superfluous, since it's already called on an owned String (d having been moved)?

True it could just be removed there.

Thank you for your detailed explain. I have to keep s and d valid after assignment, and v is a member of struct. Rust compiler tell me method 1 could be: let v = s.clone().unwrap_or(d.clone()); I think this may be more efficient than before and is the same with method 2.

The question is a bit underspecified: an Option can hold either a value, or None, so you will have to:

Extract the value if it is there
Get the default value otherwise
Have a resulting string corresponding to the initial value (or default)

Now this could be approached in different ways: if you want to consume your initial value, you want to do:
fn copy_or_default(s: Option<String>, default: String) -> String {
    s.unwrap_or(default)
}

If you would rather take a copy as you seem to suggest by cloning it:
fn copy_or_default(s: &Option<String>, default: String) -> String {
    s.clone().unwrap_or(default)
}

If you don't have ownership of the default, you may want to copy it as well:
fn copy_or_default(s: &Option<String>, default: &String) -> String {
    s.as_ref().unwrap_or(default).clone()
}

Each of these three are doing separate things, w/r to the ownership of the original string. If you just want a quick and dirty copy of a short string, it probably doesn't matter, but if your string is (e.g.) some massive multi-megabytes JSON-encoded blob, it may make a difference.
I think in the end, you probably just want to find the one that:

Does what it should...
... while communicating the intent as clearly as possible. (on that, @cafce25's comment below makes the very good point that if you are cloning the value, it is probably better to call the function clone_XXX rather than the more fuzzy copy_XXX term)

Now for the complexity of unwrapping the option, passing the default, and performing the copy, given that you are doing all three of these things, there is no way around it, except if you have a specific use-case for it, where you may want to do all of that within a function for that specific purpose, where your code would become:
let s = Some("hello".to_string());
let d = "world".to_string();
let v = my_copy_string_with_default(s, d);

But the implementation of my_copy_string_with_default would necessarily involve these three operations I think.

Nit: Calling something copy_* that in fact does a clone internally might be unexpected, at least in the Rust ecosystem.

You should not take &Option<..> to begin with, in almost all case prefer Option<&..> instead, similarly you should replace &String with &str as the latter is more general

I would probably write it with S: Deref<Target=str> or something, but I felt this was not really addressing the core of the question. That's a good point though.
